# GPS and Compass reading

Tags: google-maps, gps

I'm trying to do the following: Take a GPS reading (lat/long) and a compass reading and place a second point on a map 100 meters from the GPS reading in the compass direction.

(using Google Maps)

How could this be accomplished? Ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say in the compass direction, do you mean north/south? It is fairly easy to plot a circle that is 100m in diameter on a map. To draw a line in, point 100m from the current location in a direction is simple [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry).

Answer (score 0):

you location see import `com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;`

```
MyLocationOverlay myLoc = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
```

but you can create yourself location ... using services ....

i hope it can help you